Get Ad details in JSON instead of HTML in Facebook Meta Ads Library
I am using /ads_archive docs search endpoint to search for Facebook archived ads. It returns data in JSON format. Easy to parse and to work with. However, it only contains short info about Ad.
More detailed info is under ad_snapshot_url of format https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id={AD_ID}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}. You need to go to this URL and parse HTML, which is very uncomfortable. Info is stored inside javascript objects. Not easy to work with.
Is there any Facebook API alternative for ad_snapshot_url that returns data in JSON format?
Tried to put Accept-Language: application/json into request headers.
Tried different formats like:
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/ads_archive/{AD_ID}
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/ads_archive/ad/{AD_ID}
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/ads_archive/details/{AD_ID}
No luck.

Hey @PATAPOsha, have you been able to make a progress on this? Were there any other way to get info on an archived ad other than browsing ad_snapshot_url?
